# Why is there "No recipients defined" error?

Tags: nodemailer

There is a code:

```
const {email, text} = req.body;

const myEmail = "myemail@gmail.com"

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'myOtherEmail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'myOther`sEmailPassword'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: email,
    to: myEmail,
    subject: "some subject",
    text
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

It gets "No recipients defined" error, why? I use express for server and "email", "text" variables I get from request

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error occurs when value assigned to key to in object given to sendMail method is empty. As we see it means that something wrong happens and you don't get the same data on the server-side, as you sent in client.

Also I recommend to check if you are accessing good variable on your server-side action. Probably POST params are accessible in different way - please check this in your framework documentation.

Comment: did you mange to fix this issue?